# Why don't most of the highly educated people in poorer part of Europe migrate to the Western part?

Tags: euro-area, migration, demographics

There are a lot of people working in universities in countries like Ukraine, Belarus, Romania, Bulgaria, Poland, and so on with low salaries. Those people have high skills and education.

I saw some students pursuing PhDs in those countries with low salaries when they can just cross the border to earn much more.

Why don't most of them migrate to Western Europe?

What factors bind them in their countries?

Comment: @mootmoot, that is what EU was for.

Comment: @mootmoot, doesn't make sense. someone has to pay taxes irrespective of his job location.

Answer (score 6):

There are numerous reasons why one would want to stay in a particular country even though earning power is lower.  These are usually summarized as "frictions" in the labor market.

Culture, familiarity with an area, language, family are all non-negligible "frictions".

I note that while there will be a tendency to vote this closed as not economic, I think the reminder that there are meaningful human incentives other than money and tangible goods may be worth remembering.

Comment: I guess, only two factors are to be noted: (1) language, (2) personal motivation. Even (1) depends on (2). There could be no other factors.

Answer (score 3):

Occupational licensing may be one reason why:

> Occupational licensing is not unique to the United States. Based on
>   information gathered in 2012 from the then twenty- seven  nations  in 
>   the  European  Union  (EU),  between  9  and  24  percent  of 
>   European  workers  are  subject  to  occupational   licensing, which
>   translates to between 19 million and 51 million individuals. These
>   estimates of the share of the workforce  that is licensed, even at the
>   higher end, are still lower than the estimated share in the United
>   States, which is slightly under  30 percent (Koumenta et al. 2014).
>   Similar  to  U.S.  states,  the  extent  of  occupational  licensing 
>   varies  widely  across  countries  in  the  EU:  Bulgaria,  Estonia,
>   Finland, France, Ireland, Latvia, Lithuania, Malta, the Netherlands,
>   Romania, and Sweden all have less than 15 percent  of  their  workers 
>   covered  by  occupational  licensing  (Koumenta  et  al.  2014). 
>   Regulation  is  much  more  prevalent  in  other   countries, however:
>   at least 25 percent of the workforce in Denmark and Germany, for
>   example, is regulated, and rates are  also high in Italy and Spain.

Reforming Occupational Licensing Policies
[Morris M. Kleiner (2015)](https://www.brookings.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/THP_KleinerDiscPaper_final.pdf)

"We also find evidence that intra-EU migrants are less likely to be found in regulated occupations."
Occupational Regulation in the EU andUK: Prevalence and Labour Market Impacts 
[Koumenta, Humphris, Kleiner, and Pagliero (2014)](http://%20www.busman.qmul.ac.uk/media/sbm/research/researchcentres/cred/impact-reports/Occupational-Regulation-Koumenta.pdf)

This channel disproportionately benefits richer and more skilled workers (at least in the USA)

> [L]icensing can shift resources from workers with lower-income and 
>   fewer  skills  to  those  with  higher  income  and  skills. Data show
>   that 52 percent  of  licensed workers  hold  a Bachelor’s degree, 
>   compared  to 38 percent  of  unlicensed  workers. Lower-income 
>   workers  are  less  likely  to  be  able  to  afford  the  tuition 
>   and  lost  wages  associated  with licensing’s educational
>   requirements, closing the door to many licensed jobs for them. It is
>   also lower-income workers who are hurt if wages fall in unlicensed
>   jobs, since on average, unlicensed workers earn 28 percent less than
>   licensed workers.
>   [OCCUPATIONAL LICENSING:A FRAMEWORK FOR POLICYMAKERS (USA (2015))](https://obamawhitehouse.archives.gov/sites/default/files/docs/licensing_report_final_nonembargo.pdf)

Comment: +1 And even if there were no occupational licensing, skills and knowledge relevant to one country may not be wholly transferable to another.  Eg someone with an established career as a lawyer in Poland would probably need considerable re-training to be effective as a lawyer in the UK.

Comment: Do a university professor or a Ph.D. student need occupational licensing? I guess not. This answer is a trivial one. Law and medical are highly specialized areas.